# Is there a way to shorten my code that changes certain strings? CLOSED

Tags: python

Ok so I have this massive chunk of code and all it does is add an "o " before single-digit numbers. Is there a way to compress this?

```
minuteStr = '8'    

if minuteStr == '9':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '8':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '7':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '6':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '5':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '4':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '3':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '2':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
elif minuteStr == '1':
    minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
```

Comment: Why are you putting "o" in front of each when it doesn't matter? you could just do `miuteStr = 'o' + minuteStr`

Comment: `minuteStr.rjust(2, 'o')` ? You may have to put some validation around it to check if minuteStr is >=1 and <= 9, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

> add an "o " before single-digit numbers

```
minuteStr = '8'
if len(minuteStr) == 1 and minuteStr.isdigit():
   minuteStr = 'o ' + minuteStr
```

Comment: There is an issue if `minuteStr = '0'`, you have to add this condition to your `if` statement: `and minuteStr != '0' `